# Multiple Entry schengen visa second trip

Tags: visas, schengen, multiple-entry

I have a 6 month multiple entry visa issued by Netherlands, i've already completed my first trip to Netherlands(which was 5 days) and now i want to go Spain for 2 weeks, would it be violation of schengen rules to use visa that way?
Edit:
My concern is that in result by the end of the visa i will be spending more time in Spain than in Netherlands, is it okay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, since you have a multiple entry schengen.

Comment: My concern is that in result by the end of the visa i will be spending more time in Spain than in Netherlands, is it okay?

Comment: Yes, it's okay. I had a similar situation, my schengen visa was issued by Italy and later I used it to go to France for more days, than I spent in Italy.

Comment: Given that the SP asks both 'would it be a violation?' and 'is it OK?' you might want to clarify 'no'.

Comment: To be fair @airbear responded before i've edited my post to include clarification